# OpenWRT sending invalid packets to WAN when Android phone connects

Tags: networking, router, android, nat, openwrt

I have a Netgear WR703N wireless router flashed with OpenWRT 12.09 "Attitude Adjustment" connected to my school's Ethernet network, and our IT department sent emails alerting me that it's "transmitting traffic using IP source addresses other than that assigned for its use".

To understand the problem, I used WireShark (running on a PC with two bridged Ethernet interfaces) to capture all traffic to and from the router's WAN port.

The router is configured to give out DHCP addresses in `172.31.252.0/24` for its LAN. During this session its WAN IP address is `128.112.84.131`.The display filter was set to `eth.addr == [WAN MAC address] and not (ip.addr == [WAN IP])`, to filter out packages that originate from (or destined for) my router's WAN interface but does not contain its WAN IP address. The result is as follows (actual MAC addresses redacted):

```
No.     Time           Source                Source MAC            Destination           Dest MAC              Protocol Length Info
   3721 110.017401000  0.0.0.0               Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     255.255.255.255       Broadcast             DHCP     393    DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x6f5ef88b
   3726 110.021627000  128.112.133.220       Cisco_ee:ee:ee        128.112.85.26         Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     ICMP     98     Echo (ping) request  id=0x07ea, seq=1917/32007, ttl=253
   3727 110.021831000  128.112.84.1          Cisco_ee:ee:ee        128.112.85.26         Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     DHCP     436    DHCP Offer    - Transaction ID 0x6f5ef88b
   3728 110.022513000  0.0.0.0               Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     255.255.255.255       Broadcast             DHCP     405    DHCP Request  - Transaction ID 0x6f5ef88b
  13399 511.164980000  74.125.131.139        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     100.145.36.223        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        TCP      54     https > 60697 [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0
  13406 511.174715000  74.125.131.188        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     100.145.36.223        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        TCP      54     hpvroom > 54853 [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0
  13412 511.247461000  74.125.131.188        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     100.145.36.223        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        TCP      54     hpvroom > 54853 [RST] Seq=348 Win=0 Len=0
  13415 511.459710000  74.125.131.139        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     100.145.36.223        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        TCP      54     https > 60697 [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0
  13440 511.731825000  74.125.131.188        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     100.145.36.223        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        TCP      54     hpvroom > 54853 [RST] Seq=348 Win=0 Len=0
  13487 512.052710000  74.125.131.139        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     100.145.36.223        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        TCP      54     https > 60697 [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0
  13493 512.122466000  74.125.131.188        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     100.145.36.223        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        TCP      54     hpvroom > 54853 [RST] Seq=348 Win=0 Len=0
  13500 512.159712000  74.125.131.139        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     100.145.36.223        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        TCP      54     https > 60697 [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0
  13537 512.522715000  100.145.36.223        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     74.125.131.188        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        TCP      93     [TCP ACKed unseen segment] 54853 > hpvroom [FIN, PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=348 Win=1357 Len=27 TSval=734000 TSecr=2909129314
  13544 512.674464000  100.145.36.223        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     74.125.131.188        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        TCP      189    [TCP Retransmission] 54853 > hpvroom [FIN, PSH, ACK] Seq=4294967201 Ack=348 Win=1357 Len=123 TSval=734016 TSecr=2909129314
  13591 512.927091000  74.125.131.188        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     100.145.36.223        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        TCP      54     hpvroom > 54853 [RST] Seq=349 Win=0 Len=0
  13602 513.258968000  74.125.131.139        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     100.145.36.223        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        TCP      54     https > 60697 [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0
  13642 514.640598000  100.145.36.223        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     74.125.131.188        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        TCP      189    [TCP ACKed unseen segment] [TCP Retransmission] 54853 > hpvroom [FIN, PSH, ACK] Seq=4294967201 Ack=349 Win=1357 Len=123 TSval=734212 TSecr=2909130121
  18007 685.005464000  Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     ARP      60     Who has 128.112.84.131?  Tell 128.112.84.1
  18008 685.005643000  Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        ARP      60     128.112.84.131 is at ec:88:8f:ff:ff:ff
  18012 685.136301000  Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     ARP      60     Who has 128.112.85.26?  Tell 128.112.84.1
  18116 689.070537000  58.17.52.14           Cisco_ee:ee:ee        128.112.85.26         Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     ICMP     78     Echo (ping) request  id=0x300c, seq=0/0, ttl=40
  19496 745.150864000  Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     ARP      60     Who has 128.112.85.26?  Tell 128.112.84.1
  30283 1224.998095000 Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     ARP      60     Who has 128.112.84.131?  Tell 128.112.84.1
  30284 1224.998246000 Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        ARP      60     128.112.84.131 is at ec:88:8f:ff:ff:ff
  42190 1732.009084000 100.185.169.31        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     103.7.31.151          Cisco_ee:ee:ee        TCP      54     58291 > https [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=1357 Len=0
  42285 1733.097086000 100.185.169.31        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     103.7.31.151          Cisco_ee:ee:ee        TCP      54     [TCP Retransmission] 58291 > https [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=1357 Len=0
  42347 1735.277968000 100.185.169.31        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     103.7.31.151          Cisco_ee:ee:ee        TCP      54     [TCP Retransmission] 58291 > https [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=1357 Len=0
  43141 1764.992183000 Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     ARP      60     Who has 128.112.84.131?  Tell 128.112.84.1
  43142 1764.992460000 Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        ARP      60     128.112.84.131 is at ec:88:8f:ff:ff:ff
  55031 2304.982717000 Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     ARP      60     Who has 128.112.84.131?  Tell 128.112.84.1
  55032 2304.982956000 Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        ARP      60     128.112.84.131 is at ec:88:8f:ff:ff:ff
  70170 2844.995066000 Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     ARP      60     Who has 128.112.84.131?  Tell 128.112.84.1
  71453 2904.997024000 Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     ARP      60     Who has 128.112.84.131?  Tell 128.112.84.1
  72688 2964.972284000 Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Cisco_ee:ee:ee        Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     Tp-LinkT_ff:ff:ff     ARP      60     Who has 128.112.84.131?  Tell 128.112.84.1
```

As can be seen, packets 13399-13642 and 42190-42347 indeed originated from my router, and has a source IP different from its assigned WAN IP. Both bursts of packets were triggered when my Android phone, being connected to a different wireless network, *switched to the router's wireless network*. (This other wireless network assigns IPs from `10.8.*.*`.) The second time it happened, I was staring at the phone, and noticed the signal bars briefly flashed "H" when the WiFi connection is being established, so it looks like the phone connected to the cellular data network for a split second when switching WiFi networks.

I also tried switching between router's wireless network, other wireless network and cellular in different ways, but cannot trigger the invalid packets reliably.

After reading some online sources about "NAT leakage", I put the following command in my firewall script before the capture and verified its presence in `iptables -t filter -L`, but it did not help.

```
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -o wan -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
```

So, my questions are:

1. *How and why did this happen?* Where do these packets come from? How should I investigate this further?
2. *How do I prevent these packets from going out the WAN interface?*

Please tell me if you need more information.